# Maven-Release-Plugin: Force to use specific version of scm provider

Tags: git, maven, maven-release-plugin

I'm in the process of trying to migrate our repository from SVN to Git and I'm having trouble with the release plugin on a very large project.

Problem:

There are about 50+ sub-modules to this project and it tries to add all the modified poms as one 'git add -- '. This breaks the windows command line limit.

Fortunately a fix was put in for this in release 1.8.1 of maven-scm-provider-gitexe however the maven-release-plugin is currently set up to use 1.7 which does not have the fix.

I have tried adding the following to my root pom.xml but I can still see it downloading 1.7 during mvn release:prepare and even running the process in verbose mode gives no indication that it is using 1.8.1.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>perform</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <pomFileName>subproj/pom.xml</pomFileName>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-scm-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-gitexe</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>
```

I have also tried adding the following to the pom.xml in case that forces it to use the right version with no more luck.

```
<extensions>
    <extension>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-gitexe</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.1</version>
    </extension>
</extensions>
```

The reason I suspect it is not using 1.8.1 is that it still fails trying to do a git add with all the pom files whereas I have checked the plugin source code which definitely looks like it should be adding each file individually for Windows (I've even double-check the codehaus plexus Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS) to ensure that is returning true on my machine.

What am I missing? How can I force the release plugin to use the right version of the scm plugin?

Comment: Why move to GIT? (other than, *it's cool*) ? Just wondering, since there's nothing wrong with SVN.

Comment: First i would suggest to use an up-to-date version of maven-release-plugin cause the current version is 2.4.1. Apart from that what kind of error messages do you got during the release cycle?

Comment: I've tried with 2.4.1 with no further luck. I used 2.3.2 because the release-plugin page suggested that if you use Git (though it didn't specify why).

Comment: @vikingsteve: Seriously, if you don't know the benefits of moving to Git, then you should not be making such comments. I doubt he's moving just because "it's cool". I worked at a bank where they migrated all their code base from Subversion to Git (using Github Enterprise). The branching, merging and release time was shortened by a massive number.

Comment: @carlspring Well aware of the benefits, just that they need to be weighed against the learning curve and the headaches. Glad to hear that you found an overall time / efficiency benefit, not everyone has the same experience (it depends alot on the team), so good for you.

Answer (score 4):

According to maven release plugin 2.4.1 changelog http://jira.codehaus.org/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=11144&version=19050, SCM has been fall back to 1.7 in this version due to a bug with 'git status --porcelain'.

- So you should try the 2.4 version. It should work and maybe you will not be affect with the bug.
- Or wait for a future version ...

EDIT :
The bug is related to this SCM bug : http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SCM-686

A comment says to use `maven-scm-provider-gitexe` AND `maven-scm-provider-git-commons` as dependencies

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-gitexe</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-git-commons</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.1</version>
   </dependency>       
</dependencies>
```

Comment: +1: Or... contribute a patch so that the 2.4.2 version could fix it. :)

Comment: I add the related SCM bug. Does it work if you add the maven-scm-provider-git-commons too ?

Comment: I've tried adding those. 2.4 doesn't work because it uses 1.8 of the maven-scm-provider-etc and the particular fix I'm looking for is in 1.8.1. This: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SCM-697. Awarding you the bounty for most helpful answer. I think I'll just have to wait.

Comment: Thanks ;) (Sorry that finally it could not really help you)

Comment: @Wysawyg, check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/20912300/2916086 - I think I dealt with the same problem, but didn't find your question in time.

Comment: The issues have been moved and can be found at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SCM-686 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SCM-697

Answer (score 1):

Silly question but, have you thought about moving all these sub modules in their own git projects? And release them separately?

Comment: This is not a silly suggestion at all. I was going to recommend it myself.

Comment: The problem is that a bit part of what we want to do is release from the root so that everything gets versioned together. Otherwise we need to spend a lot of time updating interlinked dependencies whereas the release plugin takes care of that for you.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested Aurelien, extract the sub-projects into separate modules. Following this principle will make your life simpler. You won't have to release modules which don't have changes, just for the sake of releasing. Furthermore, the build time will be taken down. If you have a look at most Java projects hosted on Github, you'll see that a lot of people have extracted each of their modules into separate projects. Git is mainly meant to work with smaller repositories.

You can extract the history of the sub-directory like this:

```
git remote rm origin
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter ${project} HEAD
git remote add origin git@foo.com:path/to/${project}.git
git branch --set-upstream master origin/master
git push
```

Not the king of answer you were looking for, I believe, but I think this could help you get on the right path and, if you don't move all your projects like this, at least, it will shorten your list, and, maybe help you workaound the problem.