# Using maven-release-plugin with git-1.8.5

Tags: git, maven-release-plugin

When using git-1.8.5, with maven-release-plugin (tested with versions 2.4.2 and 2.3.2) with mvn (tested with versions 3.1.1 and 3.0.5), running `mvn release:prepare` and `mvn release:prepare-with-pom` fails.

`mvn release:prepare` *fails to create* the commits that it's supposed to create:

> [maven-release-plugin] prepare for next development iteration
>   [maven-release-plugin] prepare release foo-1.0.0

and `mvn release:prepare-with-pom`  fails with a git error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.4.2:prepare-with-pom (default-cli) on project foo: Cannot remove release POMs from SCM
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] error: the following file has changes staged in the index:
[ERROR] release-pom.xml
[ERROR] (use --cached to keep the file, or -f to force removal)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

Comment: Looks like this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233718/maven-release-plugin-force-to-use-specific-version-of-scm-provider?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648894/maven-release-fails-due-to-git-failure?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to have been fixed in version 2.5 of maven-release-plugin, which was released on March 5th.

Comment: Thanks Joey, it seems that http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-862 fixes it. Another thing to watch out for is what Kelly Davis mentioned in http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-767 - haven't confirmed, but this could be an issue for multi-module projects (I believe the workaround is to add an scm tag in each child module's pom as well as in the parent pom.)

Comment: Well, I haven't seen the behaviour described in MRELEASE-767 on the (heavily) multi-module project we have at https://github.com/overturetool/overture so I suspect that the fix is ok.

Answer (score 10):

As per [Mark Derricutt's solution](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/maven-release-plugin-oddity-no-git-commit-under-mvn-3-1-1-td5777947.html#a5777968), explicitly add the maven-scm-provider-gitexe:1.8.1 dependency to the maven-release-plugin:2.4.2 plugin:

```xml
<build>
   <plugins>
      <!-- ... -->
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.4.2</version>
         <dependencies>
            <dependency>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-gitexe</artifactId>
               <!-- This version is necessary for use with git version 1.8.5 -->
               <version>1.8.1</version>
            </dependency>
         </dependencies>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

---

Background:

- git-1.8.5 introduced a breaking change to the format of `git status`, so now scripts like maven-release-plugin should use the porcelain option `git status --porcelain` instead of `git status`.
- Therefore, [Robert Scholte could not include a dependency to `maven-scm-provider-gitexe:1.8` with maven-release-plugin:2.4.2](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/maven-release-plugin-oddity-no-git-commit-under-mvn-3-1-1-tp5777947p5778044.html).
- the maven scm provider for git incorporates the fix to include the `--porcelain` flag with [maven-scm-provider-gitexe:1.8.1](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.scm/maven-scm-provider-gitexe/1.8.1), but maven-release-plugin:2.4.2 does not have its dependency for maven-scm-provider-gitexe updated yet. See https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SCM-686 for more info.
- Despite the outdated dependency, we can overwrite it by adding the dependency to 1.8.1 explicitly as shown above.